# Assign a JSON property to concated observable Array (Typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have a string array, where I do a rest call in a loop

```
for (let i of this.obj_str_array) {
  this.obj_array.push(this.defAPi.getDetailSatz(i.dsn, i.date));
}
```

The `obj_array` will be concatenated and `subscribe`d

```
Observable.concat(...this.obj_array).subscribe(res => {
  res.forEach(a => {
    this.detailSatz.push(a);
  });
});
```

That works fine. But now I want the `i.dsn` from `"obj_str_array"` in my JSON output. The JSON object has a property called `"dsn"`. But the `dsn` could be different - for example the first 10 objects of the `subscribe`d result could have a different `"dsn"` then the next 10 objects. But every Rest Call has its own `"dsn"`.

How could I assign this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the spread(`...`) and map(`.map`) operators on `Array` to do that. Give this a try:

```
Observable.concat(...this.obj_array).subscribe((res: any[]) => {
  this.detailSatz = res.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, dsn: this.obj_str_array[index].dsn }))
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Get the error message "Cannot read property 'dsn' of undefined"

Comment: Are the number of Objects in `res` the same as the number of Objects in `obj_str_array `?

Comment: Yes! I see in console.log that the error is empty during the subscribe. After the Subscription the array seems with content.